# How to preserve the 2 digit precision

Tags: c#, .net, decimal, precision, dapper

I'm struggling to find a better way to preserve the 2 digit precision for decimal variable.

Here I have divided the question in 2 steps:

**Step1:** *SQL Query*

Inorder to get a 2 digit precision in a SQL query,  I'm using

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), .....) // to get 2 digit precision
```

On execution, I'm able to achieve the 2 digit precision in my SSMS.

```
NET_TOTAL  
---------    
10.00  
12.50  
14.25
```

**Step2:** *via C# code*

Whereas in my C# code, when I tried to store the value in my C# code it is not preserving the 2 digit precision.

```
NET_TOTAL  
---------    
10       //lost my precision
12.5     //lost my precision
14.25
```

Following is my variable declaration.

```
public decimal? NET_TOTAL { get; set; }
```

But I can smell a workaround using properties, but I'm not able to get it.

I'm using

- [dapper.net](/questions/tagged/dapper.net) for database operations.
- **`FileHelper.dll`** for converting the query list to a CSV file.

I would like to know the reason and a way to solve this problem.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which code do you execute to get the values back from the database?

Comment: @Steve Not sure this is what you're asking. For database interaction I'm using Dapper.NET(for converting the SQL results to  C# list).  The query is big enough so I posted the relevant sql script piece.

Comment: I have asked this because I have had a similar problem with decimal output parameters http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613635/using-decimal-with-specific-precision-as-output-parameters-with-dapper

Answer (score 2):

Trailing zeros to the right of the decimal is not precision.
It is just presentation.

```
decimal d;
d = 10;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:N2}",d));
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, in .NET (but not SQL Server) the `decimal` type *does* track precision separately; `2M` and `2.00M` can have different internal representations, in some circumstances.

Comment: @MarcGravell OK agree they can have different internal representaions.  But 2M equals 2.00M so I would consider them the same precision.  But might be what the OP is asking for as 2.00M writes as 2.00 without formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
decimal.Round(value,decimalPoints);
```

This will return a decimal rounded upto decimalPoints.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing precision with representation. What you see in SSMS is a formatted number (a string). What you have in C# (and inside the DB) is a "true" number. In a true normally ending 0 after the decimal point aren't included.

If you want to format it you can do something like `NET_TOTAL.ToString("0.00")`

Note that there could be another problem:

```
NET_TOTAL = 1.245;

decimal sum = NET_TOTAL + NET_TOTAL;
```

the `sum` will be 2.29, but after a roundtrip to the DB NET_TOTAL will be 1.24 or 1.25 (depending on how the DB rounded 1.245) and the recalculated sum will be 2.28 or 2.3 .

Comment: Oh, means SSMS is showing it as a string?  But I'm using `CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), .....)` to get it in 2 digits.

Comment: @user1671639 If it's on your screen, it's a string :-) In memory/DB the number isn't saved as `10.2`, but as **a** binary representation of that number (I use **a** because there are various ways to represent a number in memory).

Comment: Got it.  From your updates in answer, `NET_TOTAL = 1.245;

decimal sum = NET_TOTAL + NET_TOTAL;`  I will be not perform any operation in C# code (no problem :) ).  Since this a ETL I am not supposed to change the dataType, is there any work around to still keep it as 2 digit precision?

Comment: @user1671639 You alread have the 2 digit precision, as I've written, you only need to **format** the output (using the `ToString` or the `string.Format`)

Answer (score -1):

is this acceptable:

> ```
>     private decimal? _netTotal;
>     public decimal? NET_TOTAL{
>         get{
>             return _netTotal;
>         }
>         set
>         {
>             if (value.HasValue)
>             {
>                 _netTotal = Math.Truncate(value.Value, 2); // or rounding
>             }else{
>                 _netTotal = value;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

if you want to keep the original value but present it with 2 decimal places, then you could modify the getter instead: return Math.Truncate(value.Value, 2);

Comment: Thanks.  Let me give a try and get back to you.

Comment: it really depends where you like to have the precision - if you want to just have the precision at some win form or web page, then format it at the GUI side, if you want to have 2 decimal places precision for calculation, then do it like what i said.