# Dapper.net decimal Output parameters not returning the Precision value

Tags: c#, sql, .net, dapper

I am Using Dapper for some time now and its a great ORM mapper. but recently i found an issue with decimals being passed as an Output parameter for the Stored procedures would cut off the precision and only returns the whole number.

```
var dynamicParam = new DynmaicParam();

dynamicParam.Add("decimalOut",11.25,dbtype.decimal,ParameterDirection.OutPut);
connection.execute("sp1",dynamicParam,commandType.StoredProcedures);    
decimal val = dynamicParam.Get<decimal>("decimalOut");
```

in this case val will be 11 its not returning 11.25 as it is meant to when the procedure just returns the exact out put parameter as it was passed.

we have used a work around as following where it returns the precision as well,

```
var dynamicParam = new DynmaicParam();
dynamicParam.Add("decimalOut",11.25,dbtype.double,ParameterDirection.OutPut);
connection.execute("sp1",dynamicParam,commandType.StoredProcedures);    
decimal val = dynamicParam.Get<dynamic>("decimalOut");
```

but i still think there must be a better way to handle these decimal precision problem in dapper given the fact it's an amazing ORM mapper where it supports in many data types. appreciate a better work around and thanks in Advance

Comment: H!mm... that's vexing. I expect it is because the precision and scale aren't set on the parameter. Remind me: are they available as parameters on Add?

Comment: With the dapper version I am using. The scale and precision is not available in add

Comment: the same question is asked under this thread as well and in that thread Single data type has been accepted instead of decimals when passing out the output parameter data type. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613635/using-decimal-with-specific-precision-as-output-parameters-with-dapper?rq=1

Comment: I will have to see what can be done here; this is problematic

Comment: Thankx @MarcGravell and I have seen there are new versions of dapper supports precision and scale parameter for add, but I really don't want to upgrade the dapper version right now since the code is in production and there will be lot of dependencies need to be measured.

Comment: well, then... not much I can do :) but : dapper shouldn't be a risky update

Comment: Alright. So what would be the best solution

Comment: IMO your best option is to update the lib and use the options available. If you don't have a good process for updating libs, you've already got a problem - pretending it isn't there doesn't fix it

Comment: Is 1.4 is the stable version of dapper available now. So that I can upgrade it through nuget

Answer (score 1):

You need to use precision and scale.

**Example:**

```
dynamicParam.Add("decimalOut",11.25,dbtype.decimal,ParameterDirection.OutPut, precision: 18, scale: 2);
```